# go mod " cannot find package" when I use the external package in the other file

Tags: go, go-modules

When I use go mod and I have just one `.go` file all things are ok and `go mod` can download the external package and use it but when I use the external package in the other file (not main.go file) I get this error (when run `go run main.go`)

```
test/test.go:4:2: cannot find package
```

My project structure is like this:

```
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── test
    └── test.go
```

And that is my files:

#### main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "./test"
)

func main() {
    test.Hello()
}
```

#### test.go

```golang
package test

import (
    "github.com/mehrdadep/tgomod"
)

func Hello() {
    tgomod.Print()
}
```

#### go.mod

```golang
module test

go 1.15

require github.com/mehrdadep/tgomod v1.0.1
```

#### go.sum

```golang
github.com/mehrdadep/tgomod v1.0.1 h1:4lxx7JE0pySHLbH52sidkkKBjJQFC8ZZej3zEX/RTWc=
github.com/mehrdadep/tgomod v1.0.1/go.mod h1:YIkzdF7Sf9nd+eC0ySxL+gGbsew7LvUh9vP3p7yzTi4=
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read "How to Write Go Code", since it is the official documentation which describes how to do this correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I change the

```golang
import (
    "./test"
)
```

to

```golang
import (
    "test/test"
)
```

And it works 
So what I found was that your path should be base on your module name and then add your directory to it 
In `test/test` my first test is my module name and the second one is my directory name